# Android -to call another class

Tags: android

can anyone tell me how to call another class which does not extend activity , I have searched in many forums I am not clear with that ...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean with "call"? You don't "call" classes in Java.

Comment: AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();  //then do whatever you like on this

Comment: why you have call such class which is not extend activity?.

Comment: I want to add some code which is used to upload images in twitpic ,It's just uploading images so I don't want any UI to be shown to user. Can you tell me How to Implement it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and your response to other answer, i guess you want to do something like this,

```
class UploadImages
{
  UploadImages()
  {
  }
  void uploadImagesFunc()
  {
    //some operation; 
  }
}

//In Activity, do something like following
UploadImages mUploadImages = new UploadImages();
mUploadImages.uploadImagesFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
  class_name variable = new class_name();
  variable.method_name();
```